# How wait for return value from $.getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, jquery-callback

I want to return a value from a getJson function, but the event does not take place, since getJSON  wait. I tried realized callback function but result is same.
My code is

```
function getFBName(callback) {
  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}

function handleName(a) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
  return JSON.stringify(a);
}
```

console result is true but returned value is "undefined"

Comment: What is the need of having `handleName` function here?

Comment: because i call handleName like this 'Ip':'" + getFBName(handleName) + "'

Comment: You seem to be trying to return the result synchronously, when `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, even with the use of a callback ?

Comment: I think but I dont know what is a different synchronously or asynchronously @adeno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value to return the function getFBName. You can do somthing like this:

```
function getFBName(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?")
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result.a); //assuming that exist the element a
    });
};
```

Note: You can put a breakpoint in "console.log" and check why return undefined. Make sure that you access to the result of json response correctly. 
Remember that getJSON is asynchronous

Comment: where is callback function im sory but I dont understand and I tried this code I mean tried .done function but I take same result